# How to force File.Move / File.Copy to use a specific Network Interface Card (NIC) C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a machine with several network cards. My process is very network consuming, as it copies many files over the network to a shared location on a different machine (e.g "\...").

I would like to set a dedicated NIC for that process, but the C# IO API of `File.Copy` \ `File.Move` mask the NIC that is used.

How can it be done in C# or even by using some C++ tweak under the C# project?

Answer (score 3):

`File.Move()` and `File.Copy()` don't actually have any knowlege of a network.  It relies fully on the OS to handle everything.  So if you move/copy a file to a path that happens to be a network mount... then so be it. But `Move()` and `Copy()` don't really care.

That being said, you could setup a protocol via `Sockets` that can bind to a NIC.

Say you have a `NicA` that is on "123.1.2.3" and `NicB` that is on "156.2.3.4".  Then you could create a socket and `Bind()` to the `IPAddress` that matches the NIC you care about.

Comment: Just to make it clear: just bind some socket object to the wanted NIC's IP and then the IO operations will use that IP?

Comment: Yes. That will direct your IO operations to a specific NIC.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete bodge, but you could bind a secondary IP address from an unused private range to both machines, and `File.Copy` using that.

For example, let's say your normal LAN addressing is `192.168.0.1` though `192.168.0.254` on NIC1.

On the "source" machine, bind `10.0.0.1` to NIC2.
On the "destination" machine, bind `10.0.0.2` to the NIC you'd like to use, or add it as a secondary address on an existing NIC if that's your preference.

You could then `File.Copy` to `\\10.0.0.2\share` . The OS on the source machine should figure out that NIC2 is the "least cost route" to `10.0.0.2`.